# Injection of mocks doesn't work with when clauses

Tags: java, spring, mockito, powermock

I have to test the following class, with an autowired object:

```
public class Provider {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    public Provider() {}

    public Provider(final Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    // Other code here

}
```

I created my test as follows:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class ProviderTest {

    @Mock(name="service") Service service;
    @Mock Score score;
    @InjectMocks Provider provider = new SearchResultProvider();

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        when(service.process()).thenReturn(score);
    }

    @Test
    public void my_test() {

        provider.execute(); // It fails, because service.process() returns null

        // Other code here
    }

    // Other tests here
}
```

However, when I run the test, it fails. Everything is fine, except the clause when(...) that seems to be ignored.
That causes the test to fail on the call to provider.execute(). Inside this function the call to service.process() is executed and then I would expect a "score mock" to be returned. But a null value is returned instead.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: You are doing some strange combination of PowerMock and Mockito. Why both? I think you might want to @RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class) not sure

Comment: yeah, that should be fine.... Powermockito cannot be used alone. I use it on the top of Mockito.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code show no need for powermock, I suppose there's PowerMock because some code is `final`. But the test don't *prepare* the classes to be definalized.

I will suppose the code with a final method is the `Service`

```
public class Service {
    public final Score process() {
        throw new NullPointerException("lol");
    }
}
```

Then the code won't pass, unless the test prepares the classes to be definalized :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Service.class)
public class ProviderTest {
    ...
}
```